# Contents are too large, provided 4420976 bytes, max is 3145728 when doing a snapshotsClient.commitAndClose with Google Play services

Tags: android, google-play-services

I am writing a backup functionality for my Android game and I am using the Google cloud services to save the game data using the snapshotsClient API.

It works great most of the time, but for some of my players it 100% fails. The error I receive in my logs is this:

Contents are too large, provided XXXX bytes, max is 3145728

I have researched everywhere and while 3 Megs seems to be a limit for some systems, I have seen nowhere that it is a limit for the Google play service cloud save. And why would it only affect some users? And why nobody else had this issue?

I followed the API integration on Google here:
https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/savedgames?hl=ko

Comment: The 3 MB limit is [specifically mentioned in the documentation](https://developers.google.com/games/services/common/concepts/savedgames#limits) and applies to all users and all devices. Why are you trying to save multiple megabytes of Saved Game state at all?

Comment: I guess I missed that part. And to answer your question, the game is an open world game with huge amount of data. So this is not an automatic cloud save feature ( it would take way too much bandwitch) but more a backup feature if you want to transfer your game data to another phone. The backup can take up to 20 megs. This is the best / easiest solution that I found.,